# How do I pass through a door with the Mech, in NOVA 2?

Tags: achievements, nova-2

I am on one of the first levels of NOVA 2, where I entered in a factory, and jumped in a Mech. I am then taken in a room where I have to destroy six tanks, and four Mechs; from there, I have to go in another room, but the Mech doesn't pass through the door. I tried finding another path to reach the point I should reach, but the only way seems to be passing through that door. I cannot jump off the Mech, as the "E" key doesn't seem to have any effect (and I didn't set another key instead of "E").

There are five other doors, but I can use just three of them. I was able to pass through two doors, but they take me to a room without other doors; the remaining doors are the one to which I am directed, and the one that faces on the ocean, which is blocked.

How can I pass through that door? I also tried side-walking but that didn't help.

The main objective reported is the following one:

> Get into the courtyard and clean out any resistance.

The log reports the following sentence:

> There is heavy resistance amassed outside. I would hold on to that Mech.

Comment: I have added a Nova-2 tag for you. ♪

Comment: I thought it was only Grace Note to use a grace note. `:-)` Thank you for the tag, by the way.

Comment: Well, *someone* has to help pick up the slack. Otherwise, the ♪ just keep piling up. :)

Comment: Plus, it would be unfair to leave the task of spreading the habit to just a person. `:-)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As silly as it could seem, the solution is to keep wiggling until the Mech passes through the door; this means I kept pressing the arrow keys until the Mech would pass through the door. Maybe the position of the Mech helped too; maybe it was just a coincidence, and wiggling made the trick.

Playing the game on a iPod/iPhone, you would probably use a different way.

Comment: Yup.......Just keep wiggling side to side w/ the arrow keys!! Thanks for the help

Answer (score -1):

After several tries, I went in backwards and then turned the rig around and he magically hopped out.